How can i proxy dns to another dns for my domain?
I have a domain name example.com. Now this domain is tied to cloudflare cdn (and proxy setting is enabled) and has dns records like ns1.smth.cloudflare.com, ns2.smth.cloudflare.com. A user, when visiting my website, will connect to some of ip addresses of cloudflare.
I want to keep the cloudflare cdn, but at the same time i want user NOT to connect to some of ip addresses of cloudflare (because they are often blocked by providers in my country - that is the problem).
So finally i want to run a dns server on some linux distro (like centos, etc), that will redirect requests for my domain to cloudlfare dns. Is it possible?
The goal is to tie my domain to this personal dns server and the ip shown for my domain have to be ip of my personal dns server, but not cloudlfare. And keep cloudflare working, because it speed up my site.

It is possible, but likely useless for the purpose of your stated goal.
Proxying of authoritative DNS requests can be achieved using most DNS servers like perhaps BIND9 or Unbound or Dnsmasq (fundamentally it is not very different from what DNS "caches" do), or even using raw TCP/UDP relaying in a pinch (rinetd or iptables DNAT+SNAT).
The problem with this plan is that the DNS nameservers aren't the only CloudFlare servers that your visitors have to contact. You said you want to keep the CDN feature, but literally the entire point of the CDN feature is that it's supposed to redirect your clients' actual HTTP requests to CloudFlare CDN's proxy servers instead of yours – and because those CDN servers are part of the same CloudFlare network as the DNS nameservers, their IP addresses are just as likely to be blocked as the DNS ones.

Thanks for your answer. For now, when i use dig utility to see the ip of my website, i will see some of cloudflare's ip. I want to see my own server's ip instead (but still keep cloudflare cdn working). This is the goal. The server will be located OUT my country, so there will be no problems between it's interaction with cloudflare's servers.

As I already said, that's a contradictory goal. If it shows your server's IP, then it connects to your server's IP – by definition bypassing Cloudflare CDN. Having the Cloudflare IP addresses in DNS is literally how their CDN functions.

Yes, so i will lose the cdn function, but...there is also a caching function in cloudflare (enabled). It stores the cache of my pages...anyway, i will still have it, no?

No you won't, because the users' requests will be bypassing cloudflare, so it will not have any opportunity to serve from cache. The caching is part of the CDN function (I guess you could even say that the caching is CDN). So in short, either users see your server's IP and talk to your server directly (bypassing all of Cloudflare), or users see Cloudflare's IP and talk to Cloudflare's cache/cdn.

No, caching is not cdn, of course. But it can be an additional function of cdn. So i will lose both cdn and "caching storage" function in this case...So no way to have another ip from cloudflare's on my website, if i still want to use cloudflare?

No, all of those functions rely on the client actually connecting to cloudflare first. If the user connects to your server's address, then they will be using your server's bandwidth – that's what "connecting to" means, after all.
